# How to get a variables only defined as an argument in another function in Haskell

Tags: function, variables, haskell, arguments

I have

```
cubicQ a b c = ((3*a*c) - b**2)/(9 * (a**2))
```

I need to get the value of "a" out of that so I can use it in another function, without having to pass it as an argument in that other function. The function I need to use it in is below:

```
cubicRealSolution q r s t = if p < 0 then error "NaN" else (s + t) - ((b)/(3*(a)))
```

Comment: This looks like an (almost) complete duplicate of the question you asked two minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484370/haskell-use-multiple-functions-inside-of-another-function

Comment: What do you think the values of `a` and `b` would *be*? You haven't called `cubicQ` at all, and whatever values you would use in such a call are the values you would use in `cubicRealSolution` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner: in the linked question, the OP defines a `q`, etc., but does not really makes a "function application".

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, it's not possible. If you want a function to have access to a value, you must pass that value to the function (and it must be prepared to accept it).

Comment: You can wrap a function inside another one using the `where` keyword. The wrapped function will have access to all the parameters from the function it is wrapped in. So not impossible although it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Altough this won't work we'll present you this to show the idea. In Haskell you can write

```
cubicQ a b c = ((3*a*c) - b**2)/(9 * (a**2))

    where

    cubicRealSolution q r s t = if p < 0 then error "NaN" else (s + t) - ((b)/(3*(a)))
```

The trick is to use the `where` keyword. Because `cubicRealSolution` is wrapped inside `cubicQ` it can have access to its arguments `a`, `b` and `c` without the need to pass them.