# Haskell program for calculating 3rd roots

Tags: haskell

```
The error now iCouldn't match expected type ‘Double’
          with actual type ‘Double -> Double -> Double -> Double’ , Probable cause: ‘(+)’ is applied to too few arguments
```

In the expression: cubicQ ^ 3 + r ^^ 2
  In an equation for ‘cubicDisc’: cubicDisc q r = cubicQ ^ 3 + r ^^ 2

```
 cubicR :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
cubicR a b c d = (9*a*b*c-27*a^^2*d-2*b^^3)/(54*a^^3)

cubicQ :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
cubicQ a b c = (3*a*c-b^^2)/(9*a^^2)
cubicDisc :: Double -> Double -> Double
cubicDisc q r  = cubicQ^3 + r^^2
cubicS :: Double -> Double -> Double
cubicS q r = (r + sqrt(q^^3+r^^2))**(1/3)
cubicT :: Double -> Double -> Double
cubicT q r = (r - sqrt(q^^3+r^^2))**(1/3)

cubicRealSolutions :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
cubicRealSolutions a b c d = if cubicDisc > 0 || root == 0
                             then [rootOne,rootTwo,rootThree]
                             else []
  where 

    rootOne= (cubicS + cubicT) - b/(3*a)
    rootTwo = (cubicS+cubicT)/2 -(b)/(3*a) + sqrt(3)/2*(cubicS-cubicT)
    rootThree = (cubicS+cubicT)/2 -(b)/(3*a) + sqrt(3)/2*(cubicS-cubicT)
```

Comment: hey I tried what you said and got the error: parse error on input ‘where’

Comment: the error is now: Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Comment: `cubicS`, `cubicT`, `root`, and `cubicDisc` have not been defined. The compiler is complaining that you need to define them. I'd recommend defining them in the `where`.

Comment: @DavOS I have edited everything again and I have a new error, which I have stated above the code

Comment: `cubicDisc` should be defined: `cubicDisc :: Double -> Double` and implemented as such: `cubicDisc r = cubicQ^3 + r^^2`. You'll still have errors because you are using un-applied functions `cubicS`,`cubicT` in `where`. Each needs two parameters `q` and `r` as you defined.

Comment: @DavOS I don't get how I am supposed to apply them, can you please help me

Comment: "Function application is calling a function by putting a space after it and then typing out the parameters." Please read [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)

Comment: @DavOS I keep getting parse error on input ‘where'

Comment: `cubicDisc`, `root`, `cubicS`, and `cubicT` should all have type `Double`. If you really want them to be a function, which is probably unnecessary, then you need to apply them with parameters. But for simplicity, just make them `Double`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell use multiple functions inside of another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484370/haskell-use-multiple-functions-inside-of-another-function)

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, your program does not make sense, that's what the compiler is complaining about. First, the `if` statement is just floating around; its not in the same scope as `cubicRealSolutions`. I would recommend revising and reading through some Haskell documentation on `let`, `if`, and function syntax . For now, if I were you I would clean up the code as follows:

```
cubicRealSolutions :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
cubicRealSolutions a b c d = if cubicDisc > 0 || root == 0
                             then [rootOne,rootTwo,rootThree]
                             else []
  where 
    root = 0
    rootOne= (cubicS + cubicT) - b/(3*a)
    rootTwo = (cubicS+cubicT)/2 -(b)/(3*a) + sqrt(3)/2*(cubicS-cubicT)
    rootThree = (cubicS+cubicT)/2 -(b)/(3*a) + sqrt(3)/2*(cubicS-cubicT)
    cubicDisc = 18*a*b*c*d - 4*(b^3)*d + (b^2)*(c^2) - 4*a*c^3 - 27*(a^2)*(d^2)
    cubicS    = 0.1
    cubicT    = 0.2
```

However, there are still major issues with this code and it **will not compile** because `root`,`cubicDisc`, `cubicS`, `cubicT` are not defined. Also, you never use the parameters `c` or `d` which I find odd, as you probably want to use them. Finally, `if` statements **must** evaluate to the same type, hence the `else` evaluates to an empty list instead of a string. Even my revision is not "good" style. There are too many statements in the `where` clause. If this happens its best to break the function down into smaller parts to avoid run-on `where` clauses. I've used `...` to indicate what you need to define for the compiler.

References: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where)

PS: Personally, I find `where` syntax to be easier to understand than `let` but that is up to personal style choices. Although, `let` is a bit more flexible than `where`.

EDIT: I have defined `root`, `cubicS`, and `cubicT` with placeholder values to illustrate that they must evaluate to a `Double`.

Comment: hey I tried what you said and got the error: parse error on input ‘where’

Comment: @hesamhlors Double check your indentation is correct. Only use spaces and `where` should be two spaces from the left, each line under `where` should be another two spaces from the left, total four spaces from left margin. Don't leave `...` in the code, `...` indicates that code needs to be added there. You can also edit your original question with what you have so far and please add the exact error you are receiving in code blocks. I'd be more than happy to troubleshoot your updated code!

Comment: @hesamhlors I've edited my answer to define `cubicDisc`